# Java ternary operator and postfix/prefix operations

Tags: java

I would like to understand behavior of that codes:

If we use **prefix increment:**

```
public class Ternary{
    public static void main(String[] args){
       int k=0;
       for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
          k = (k < 3) ? ++k : 0;
          System.out.println(k);
       }
    }
}
```

Output is:
    1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2

But if use **postfix increment:**

```
public class Ternary{
    public static void main(String[] args){
       int k=0;
       for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
          k = (k < 3) ? k++ : 0;
          System.out.println(k);
       }
    }
}
```

Output is:
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

What is the difference and why we don't have the same output ?

Comment: `++k` increments `k` before evaluation, `k++` takes the value of `k` and only then increment its value. Debug your code and you'll better understand this, guaranteed.

Comment: This is no different to a very common question about `k = k++;` in Java.  The increment is done before the assignment so the `++` does nothing.  In the prefix case, doing the assignment after the ++ doesn't change the result.

Comment: A suggestion: Don't ever use the pre/postfix increment/decrement except as single standing expressions like `for (i=0; i<k;i++)`. As the answers here show, few get how they work, so it is confusing. And it is an archaic relict from times where opcodes had pre/post increment flags.

Answer (score 6):

```
++k
```

Is interpreted first and then the value is used

```
k++
```

Is first used and after that the value is incremented

So in the second case you are saying

```
k = k++;
```

And that wont effectively change the value of k

Personally i would prefer something like this:

```
 k = (k < 3) ? k + 1 : 0;
```

Because you don't really want to increment k and then give k that value, that wouldn't make much sense

Perhaps see [here](http://www.c4learn.com/java/java-increment-decrement-operator/) a longer explanation

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> k = (k < 3) ? ++k : 0;
> ```

This first statement means:

1. increment k
2. evaluate (k < 3) ? (new k) : 0;
3. save result of step 2) in k

> ```
> k = (k < 3) ? k++ : 0;
> ```

This second statement means:

1. evaluate (k < 3) ? (old k) : 0;
2. increment k;
3. save result of step 1) in k (which overwrites the value of step 2)

What you are trying to achieve is better done without assigning the result of the RHS to k.

Answer (score 0):

`k++;` simply means `k = k + 1;`

`++k` means increment and then assign the new value to `k`.